# Mediator pattern in Objective-C: Controller objects to perform calculations etc.

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, design-patterns

My app performs some rather complex calculations regarding the valuation of companies. 
It fetches raw data from multiple sources (e.g. share prices from a web service stored as csv data and fundamental data as xml data).

After fetching the data, the app parses the data, stores it in Core Data and performs the calculations. The calculation results are also stored in core data.

My current approach is to have the calculations added as categories to the Company (managed) object and the parsing of csv and xml data as categories added to the data objects (not shown in the image). The network related code is in separate singleton object (as suggested in the book: iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, 3rd Edition).

**Problem:**

As the network communication and calculations are mutually dependent (i.e. some calculations can start only after a specific data package has been received) and I want to use multi-threading, I ended up with quite a lot of code in the view controller.

I believe I should use a coordinator object following the idea of the mediator pattern and free my view controller from the coordination related code.

What are your thoughts on this?

- Would the mediator pattern (coordinator object) be the right approach
  in your view?
- How would you recommend setting up the coordinator
  object?
- Are there any good tutorials or samples on this subject on the web or
  in a book?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS offers two great technologies for this - NSOperations and Grand Central Dispatch. I'm more comfortable with using operations for what your are describing, as its really easy to create connections between operations, such that something doesn't start until something else finishes. NSOperation queues work in concert with the OS so that the number of threads and general load is managed for the device and the current resources.

There is an open source project on github, "NSOperation-WebFetches-MadeEasy", that has a mediator object that you instantiate in your primary class (in this case your viewController, but can be any class), and you run all operations through it, and it messages you back on the mainThread to one method in your class. You can get going with this in 15 minutes - the class you want is OperationsRunner, and it tells you what to do to add it in the .h file. You can use this for both web fetches (concurrent NSOperations) and non-concurrent operations. You can even have block operations now.

Read up on NSOperations and blocks in Apple's [Concurrent Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me on GCD. I have recoded parts of my app to use GCD and it seems to work fine now. I did not find the open source project you mentioned, do you have an URL?

Comment: Funny - google didn't find it - URL -> https://github.com/dhoerl/NSOperation-WebFetches-MadeEasy